# Objective C does self point to parent after doing self = [super init]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I have code like the following:

```
self = [super init]
```

does self point to super? If so, why would you want this? if my instance object has the variable "someVal", I won't be able to get to it by doing [self someVal]. correct?

How then would I get to the instance variable's using self when self points to super?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does self point to super?

It's really the other way around. `super` is really the same as `self`, except that it tells the compiler to start looking for method implementations starting with the superclass rather than the class itself. You can check this by logging the value of `super` and the value of `self`; you'll find that they both point to the same address.

When you create an object, you do this:

```
Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

The `alloc` allocates the memory that will become the object you're creating, but until that memory is initialized it's just a chunk of memory -- not a valid object. If `Foo` is a subclass of `Bar` and `Bar` is a subclass of `NSObject`, then by convention Foo's initializer will call Bar's, and Bar's will call NSObject's, so that the initialization proceeds in order: first the memory is initialized by NSObjects' `-init`, and Bar's init receives the returned value and assigns it to `self`. It then proceeds to do any Bar-specific initialization, and returns `self`. Foo's `-init` then assigns the returned value to `self` again and finally does any Foo-specific initialization.

All that assigning to `self` might seem both redundant and confusing. It's really just a convention, but the purpose is to allow the superclass's initializer to return some object other than the one that was allocated, including `nil`. So, for example, if the initialization of `Bar` failed for some reason, `-[Bar init]` could return nil. The possibility that `nil` might be returned from `[super init]` is the reason we put the `self = [super init]` assignment inside a conditional: if the assigned value is `nil`, the initialization part is skipped and `nil` is returned. It's also possible that `-[Bar init]` could return a pointer to an object other than the one that was allocated, such as when an object similar to the one being created already exists and can be reused.

Most of the time, the pointer you get back from `-init` will be the same one that you got from `+alloc`, so you *could* write this:

```
Foo *f = [Foo alloc];
[f init];
```

If you write that, however, you're making an assumption that the initializers of your class and all the classes that it inherits from will *always* return the same object, and will never return `nil`. By doing that you're breaking the convention and severely hamstringing yourself and whoever wrote the classes from which Foo inherits -- they'll break your code if they return a different object in a future release of the class. Also, it'll look like you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

> does self point to super?

This question doesn't make sense in an instance method, since there `super` is not really a concrete/actual pointer-to-instance, it just indicates that the implementation of the superclass must be called. And since in the case of *most* objects (except class clusters) all methods `return self;`, then the answer is **no: the actual pointer to the instance doesn't change magically by itself.**

For the record: the exception is manifested by class clusters (most Cocoa container classes, for example, `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc.). These classes often have an initializer method that returns a different instance than the one that was originally allocated, and of which the class is a concrete subclass of the class of the original `self`. For example, an implementation of the `NSString` initializer could be:

```
@implementation NSString

- (NSString *)init
{
    [self release];
    self = [[__NSCFString alloc] init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

The reason for this is that optimizing for different types of initialization can be achieved this way.

Comment: then why store the return of [super init] at all? If self referenced from parent is the same as self from the child, there is no need to store the return of [super init] in self variable. right?

Comment: @user1099123 "most objects **(except class clusters)**" - so yes, it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Self is always pointing to one instance. When you use super you are referencing parent methods not a parent instance.

Answer (score 1):

`self` means current class' instance.

`self = [super init]` means self is getting the value returned by `[super init]`.

Comment: `self` is the current *instance*, not the current class.

Comment: @bdesham : oooppss missed somthing.